# Finding a special plane graph with some requirements on the faces

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-drawing

Is there a plane graph such that

(1) the outer face has degree 3, i.e, is a triangle,

(2) every inner face has degree 5, and

(3) any two degree 5 faces share at most one commong edge.

Comment: If you have a plane graph with a pair of inner faces of degree 5 that share more than one edge, you can simply "insert" a dodecahedron into one (or both) of the faces to alleviate the situation. So an example should be easy to construct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To supplement Gordon's answer based on my comment, here's a planar drawing:

[image: Pentagulation of the triangle]

Answer (score 7):

Using Timothy Budd's suggestion, it is easy to find such a graph by gluing two dodecahedra together. Here is the SageMath code to make this graph.

```
d1 = graphs.DodecahedralGraph()
d2 = graphs.DodecahedralGraph()
h = d1.disjoint_union(d2)
h.merge_vertices([(0,0),(1,0)])
h.merge_vertices([(0,1),(1,1)])
h.merge_vertices([(0,2),(1,2)])
h.add_edge((0,3),(1,3))
h.relabel()
```

Here is the picture

[image]

If you need to check that everything is satisfied then the below code finds all the 5-faces as sets of vertex-pairs (hence the nested "Set" stuff) and then checks all the pairwise intersections.

```
f5s = [Set([Set(e) for e in f]) for f in h.faces() if len(f) == 5]
[len(x.intersection(y)) for x in f5s for y in f5s if x != y]
```

Comment: This is a plane graph?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is planar, else Sage would complain if I tried to get its faces, Timothy Budd has provided the sensible plane drawing...

Comment: OK, very good..